# NgClass issue Angular and D3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I have an issue with [ngClass]. It doesn't add or remove the class if the Circles in the HTML aren't moving. If the circles are moving it works fine.. Does somebody know why? I dont find anything in the internet.

The isSidebarMenuOpen value is coming from a other component. I got every time the right value. This is why I think the issue is with adding the css class to the div.

If the sidebar opens, I just want to move the map to the right side with a css class

```
<div [ngClass]="{'open': isSidebarMenuOpen}">
....svg code (circles and other stuff)
</div>
```

Service.ts

```
isSidebarMenuOpenSubject = new Subject<any>();
isSidebarMenuOpen = this.isSidebarMenuOpenSubject.asObservable();

getIsSidebarMenuOpen(isSidebarMenuOpen: boolean) {
 this.isSidebarMenuOpenSubject.next(isSidebarMenuOpen)
}
```

Sidebar-Component

```
toggleSidebarMenu() {
 this.isSidebarMenuOpen = !this.isSidebarMenuOpen;
 this.resizeService.getIsSidebarMenuOpen(this.isSidebarMenuOpen);    
}
```

map-component

```
isSidebarMenuOpen = false;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.resizeService.isSidebarMenuOpen.subscribe(value =>{
  this.isSidebarMenuOpen = value
});
```

Comment: try 
```<div [ngClass.open]="isSidebarMenuOpen">
....svg code (circles and other stuff)
</div>```

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with `[ngClass]`, It must be an issue with change detection. Can you add some code snippets which can replicate the issue.

Comment: @Ravikumar can this help?

Comment: @Dario this doesn't work for me

Comment: Your code looks fine and it's hard to understand what is the. Try recreating issue in some online angular playgrounds(stackblitz, codepen, etc) and share it here.